# How to let gradlew.bat automatically run tasks?

Tags: java, batch-file, gradle, wrapper, gradlew

I was wondering if it is possible to tell the gradlew.bat of the Gradle Wrapper to automatically run tasks like "test" or "jacocoTestReport".

I tried doing that by putting lines like "gradle test" in the execute area of the gradlew.bat. It told me then that "gradle" is not a known command?

Sidequestion: I created with the gradle wrapper the 4 files (2 scripts, 1 jar, 1 properties-file). I sent the 4 files on a diffrent computer that doesnt know gradle at all and execute the gradlew.bat. It says build successful but all it did was creating an empty .gradle folder? Is that what is supposed to happen? The lack of documentation makes it really hard. I did read a lot of official gradle documentation though. But its only helping a little bit. I also googled a bunch.

I use the very default gradlew.bat file.

```
    @if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windowz variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args
if "%@eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NT_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*
goto execute

:4NT_args
@rem Get arguments from the 4NT Shell from JP Software
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%$

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "jacoco"


group = 'Calc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""


jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"

reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")

}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
testCompile "junit:junit:4.+"
}

test {
jacoco {
    append = false
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
    classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
}
}

jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
}
classDirectories = files('build/classes/') 
}
```

Comment: You're not intended to modify `gradlew.bat` or `gradlew`... it's supposed to be a wrapper for Gradle that will download the version of Gradle required if you don't already have it.

Comment: Running `gradlew test` should be the same as running `gradle test` but with the aforementioned check and download (if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this in your [build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#setDefaultTasks(java.util.List)) if you'd like. Just add the following:

```
defaultTasks = ['test']
```